# get items from session attribute

Tags: javascript, jsp

There is list of `Request` objects as session attribute `requests`. How to get items from there in javascript code? `Request` has fields `id,requestId,beds,days,fio`. Session attribute has name `requests`.

I set session attribute

```
session.setAttribute("requests", adminService.getUncheckedRequests());
```

It's  a list of objects `List<Request>`. 
Request is object

```
public class Request extends Entity {
private int beds;
private Long classId;
private int days;
private int isChecked;
private String fio;
public int getBeds() {
    return beds;
}
public void setBeds(int beds) {
    this.beds = beds;
}
public Long getClassId() {
    return classId;
}
public void setClassId(Long classId) {
    this.classId = classId;
}
public int getDays() {
    return days;
}
public void setDays(int days) {
    this.days = days;
}
public int getIsChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}
public void setIsChecked(int isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
}
public String getFio() {
    return fio;
}
public void setFio(String fio) {
    this.fio = fio;
}
}
```

How to get items of this attribute in javascript code

```
function getItems() {
   //get list of objects and iterate through it
}
```

Comment: what is what!!!put up your code instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly. Session is stored on server, while the JS is executed in the client's browser. To access session variables from javascript you can send a ajax request to the web server and return desired variables to the JS as a response to that request.

Comment: Can you provide a link to example?

Comment: I dont have a full example, but if you are using jQuery you can find a example here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ (second example from the bottom). You will need to serialize Request java objects to something more suitable for sending over HTTP. Then you can use the sample code from the link, but keep in mind that you will probably have an array of request objects, not just one.

Comment: Forgot to mention that when i said 'someting more suitable' i ment JSON in this example